# Error getting weblogic 12.2.1.3, when we deploy war

Tags: java, spring-boot, weblogic12c

it's working when we start server and deploy war from installed wl location. now copy same domain to another location, then start server and deploy. its create folder ".appmergegen" and throw below error

Error:

> Unable to access the selected application.
>   Message icon - Error Illegal character in opaque part at index 26: zip:../domain_12.2.1.3/servers/AdminServer/tmp/.appmergegen_1522233675847/Modis-App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/dg1r28/war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/web-fragment.xml

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING???

Comment: Lots of presser to resolve the same.